# Python: String not recognizing two digit numbers up to a certain amount

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, output, run-length-encoding

I have a function where a user inputs a certain string that may either be encoded or decoded. This has to follow run-length. I have trouble focusing on decoding. The function works perfectly fine if I were to input "a7bc3", but it doesn't work if it were to have a two digit number like "b2hm11". The output is supposed to be "bbhmmmmmmmmmmm" (if you count there are 11 m's).

How can I make this function recognize two-digit numbers or have numbers set to a certain range? I have tried in the code below in comments by setting up a conditional statement. It doesn't work. I want to maintain my recursive logic in this function.

Code below:

```
def decode(user_input):
    if len(user_input) < 2:
        return user_input

    char = user_input[0]
    num = user_input[1]

    # if user_input in range(0, 9):
    #     num = user_input[1]
    # else:
    #     break

    if num.isdigit():
        return char * int(num) + decode(user_input[2:])
    else:
        return char + decode(user_input[1:])

print(decode("b2hm11"))
print(decode("abu6"))
```

Comment: Where/how is this code even *attempting* to determine multi-digits substrings?

Comment: @ScottHunter it should be recognizing it the second following string under num=user_input[1] because this follows the run-length format.

Comment: `user_input[1]` is a single character.

Comment: @ScottHunter How do I make sure that the next character is not a number so double-digit numbers would not be recognized?

Comment: @Jab I don't believe there is a builtin called `char`; did you mistake it for `chr`?

Comment: haha @Tomothy32 you're right. Time for me to goto bed... I'm seeing things

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with but be warned that I did this late at night so it probably won't be the best it can be.

```
def decode(user_input):
    if len(user_input) < 2:
        return user_input

    char = user_input[0]

    if user_input[1].isdigit():
        endNumber = False
        index = 1
        while not endNumber:

            if not user_input[index].isdigit():
                endNumber = True
            else:
                if index == len(user_input) - 1:
                    index += 1
                    endNumber = True
                else:
                    index += 1

        return char * int(user_input[1:index]) + decode(user_input[index:])
    else:
        return char + decode(user_input[1:])

print(decode("b2hm11")) #outputs bbhmmmmmmmmmmm
print(decode("abu6")) #outputs abuuuuuu
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I'm still pretty new to python but what does "while not endNumber" mean?

Comment: endNumber is a variable that I set as False to use to exit the for loop when it gets to the next character. If you have used while True before this is similar because it is essentially while not true. So when we change endNumber to True it will exit the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulate using this:

```
import re
Str = "3b42hm5a67"
re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]|-?\d+\.\d+|\d+',Str)
#output: ['3', 'b', '42', 'h', 'm', '5', 'a', '67']
```

Here's one way, without recursive func calls:

```
import re
def decode(inString):
    result=""
    String=re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]|-?\d+\.\d+|\d+',inString)
    if len(String)<2:
        return String[0]
    else:
        for i in range(len(String)):
            if String[i].isdigit():
                result +=  String[i-1] * (int(String[i])-1)
                i+=1
            else:
                result += String[i]
                i+=1            
    return result

print(decode("M"))      #M  <== output
print(decode("abu6"))   #abuuuuuu
print(decode("b2hp11")) #bbhppppppppppp
```